# DPM 2012 - recovering files - How?

Tags: scdpm

Having installed DPM 2012 and created a protection group with a server and selecting a folder on that server when I come to do a recovery it seems I have to recover the whole folder.

Am i missing something; how do I recover a single file from that folder being protected?

Jason

Comment: Are you doing host-based backups (i.e. backing up an entire VM, the equivalent to imaging), or filesystem backups?

Comment: Not backing up an entire VM; just choosing to backup a server
( Physical) and then choose the folder on that server to backup.  
cheers, J

Answer (score 1):

For some reason when in remote desktop it was very hard to click on the folder. when on the main console I've just realised that you need t double click the folder and then you can see the files under it. doh!